# procedure versus macro within top level environment

Tags: macros, scheme, closures, environment

I would appreciate your help to understand the difference in behaviour between procedure and macro in the cases described here-after.

**Situation 1 (procedure)**

```
(define bar (lambda (x) (foo x))) ; closure of 'bar' contains top-level...
; ... environment where 'foo' is not bound yet
;
(define foo (lambda (x) (* x 4))) ; now, 'foo' is bound in top-level environment
;
(bar 2) ; ==> 8 ; when this line is evaluated, 'foo' is available in ...
; ... the top-level environment, so in the closure of 'bar'
```

This seems sound to me.

**Situation 2 (macro)**

Let's try to use a macro instead of a procedure in the 2nd line:

```
(define bar (lambda (x) (foo x))) ; closure of 'bar' contains...
; ... top-level environment where 'foo' is not bound yet
;
(define-syntax foo
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((foo arg1) (* 4 arg1)))) ; I thought that 'foo' was bound in...
; ... top-level environment to the macro
;
(bar 2) ; ==> ERROR: reference to undefined identifier: foo
```

**I do not understand the error. Why isn't the binding "foo <--> macro" visible when (bar 2) is evaluated whereas it is in the top-level environment, so in the closure of 'bar'?**

Swapping the 1st and 2nd line resolves the problem, but I do not understand why:

```
(define-syntax foo
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((foo arg1) (* 4 arg1)))) 
;
(define bar (lambda (x) (foo x))) 
;
(bar 2) ; ==> 8
```

Thanks in advance for your help! :-)

Yours sincerely,

Nicolas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the working version, because the macro was already defined, the system will expand the macro, so you effectively get:

```
(define bar (lambda (x) (* 4 x)))
```

However, in the non-working version, the macro wasn't yet defined, and it doesn't get expanded. At run-time, the `bar` function expects to find the `foo` procedure, which doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! :) (to be continued)

Comment: When does the expansion take place? I thought it was when (bar 2) is interpreted, because it is at that time that we need to know what 'foo' is. And, at that time, the macro is defined. So, I do not understand yet. Thanks again!

Comment: @Nicholas_75: No, the macro is expanded at the point of the `lambda`. :-)

Comment: Thanks! Your answer and additional reading helped me to understand my misconception of macro in Scheme. I will further think about it. :-)